# How to close command prompt window triggered by xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our stage environment ,we want run exe automatically based on errors .Below is the code i am using

```
declare @minid int    
declare @maxid int     
select @minid=min(sno) from activityid    
select @maxid =max(sno) from activityid    
declare @cmd varchar(8000)    
declare @cmd2 varchar(8000)    
set @cmd='E:\Debug\Debug\Acces.exe  /ly /activityId '    
declare @ad int    
declare @cmd1 varchar(8000)    
while @minid<=@maxid    
begin    
select @ad=ad from activityid where sno=@minid--get activity    
set @cmd2=@cmd+cast(@ad as varchar(8000))    
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd2    
set @minid=@minid+1    
end
```

So everytime in loop ,a new exe is being triggered.

How can i close the exe after execution, irrespective of success or failure .

Please note that this i have to do from sql only to send emails and this is stage,so we need not bother about xp_cmdshell disadvantages.

Comment: What is "Acces.exe" and what are its other command-line switches?

Comment: total parameters need for access.exe are below  access.exe /ly /activityid 540

Comment: Hi there. Yes, I see those two command-line options from your question. I am asking what are ALL of the options available to "Acces.exe". It is possible that there is one to "exit".

Comment: i dont think there is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you really can't close the exe... that's up to the exe to do, unless you KILL it or something. If you're going to run an executable like this from a command shell, you have to make sure it behaves in the manner you need it to. You're basically at the mercy of the executable until it finishes and exits.